# Is it required to update the Database Version when updating a new APK?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application on the Play store. This application contains a database file with Version-1 at time of launching application. Now I have to update an application so that I change Version-Code and Version-Name and there is no change in the database file.

So my question is that, is it fine that I don't change the Database Version and update my Application on the Play store? Is there any issue in the next update?

Comment: If there truly is "no change in Database file" -- no new tables, columns, indexes, etc. -- then you do not need to increment your database schema version. You only need to increment the database schema version when the database schema changes.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for reply. So there is not any issue in future if i change DB version. is it?

Comment: "So there is not any issue in future if i change DB version. is it?" -- you should be able to change the database schema version sometime in the future without a problem. Again, you *only* increment the database schema version when you change the database schema. There is no requirement that you have to change the database schema for every release of your app.

Comment: Note that I cannot rule out something possibly odd with Play Store distribution, which is why I am commenting rather than answering, but I would be stunned if there is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

DB and application version have no connection.

Your app will work fine

Comment: Why (-1)?? the asker said there is no change in DB so how is it connected to the app version??